# Ruby skips if statements

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby program here w/c consists of hashes. Basically when the user enters l or p or sc it will check if the computer generated key matches the criteria on the first variable w/c is the player or the user. If it matches the criteria it will return you won. But if it's not it will return you loose. otherwise if it's the same it will print a tie.

```
MY_CHOICES = { 
 'l' => 'light',
 'p' => 'paper', 
 'sc' => 'scan',
}

def test?(first, second)
  (first == 'p' && second == MY_CHOICES ['l']) ||
  (first == 'l' && second == MY_CHOICES ['p']) ||
  (first == 'sc' && second == MY_CHOICES ['sc']) ||
  (first == 'l' && second == MY_CHOICES ['l'])
end 

def print_results(player, computer)
  if test?(player, computer)
    puts("You won!")
  elsif test?(computer, player)
    puts("Computer won! You loose!")
  else
    puts("It's a tie!")
  end
end

puts "Enter a key: "
choice = gets().chomp()
computer_choice = MY_CHOICES.values.sample
print_results(choice, computer_choice)
puts("You chose: #{choice}, computer choose: #{computer_choice}"
```

With the codes above, my code is skipping the codes and always prints "It's a tie" I don't what I am missing here. Any idea?

Comment: @etusm: What problem do you see with that?

Comment: You're using a different set of possible choices for the player and the computer -- is that intentional?

Comment: @Linuxios: Fixed it.

Comment: @JohnCarter: And is it still broken?

Comment: @JohnCarter Please fix the bugs in the code that you've posted here. And your code is working fine for me(after fixing minor bugs). Maybe try hardcoding the value of `computer_choice` to see if its working.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting the user's input and testing it against 'rock', 'paper' and 'scissors', however you've stated that the user is entering 'l', 'p', and 'sc' so test will never evaluate to true

As an example, saving this as rps.rb and running:

```
> ruby rps.rb 
Enter a key: 
rock
You won!
You chose: rock, computer choose: light
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried fixing your code a bit:

```
def test?(player, computer)
  (player== 'rock' && computer== VALID_CHOICES['sc']) ||
  (player== 'paper' && computer== VALID_CHOICES['r']) ||
  (player== 'scissors' && computer== VALID_CHOICES['sc']) ||
  (player== 'paper' && computer== VALID_CHOICES['sp'])
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this solves the problem -- all you did was change the parameter names.